# Android Java Return Type Error

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and following some tutorials online. However, fragments appeared to have changed since the tutorial was published. Now I am stuck on an error that I cannot seem to resolve. I am getting the error "The return type is incompatible with `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)`" on the return type of the `getItem` method. Any idea why? If I change the return type to `FriendsFragment`, I get the same error. If I change the return type to Fragment then I get errors inside the method. Please help! Thanks in advanced. Here is my code:

```
package com.erinkabbash.ribbit;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    protected Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public InboxFragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).

        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return new InboxFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FriendsFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do an override unless the signature matches exactly.  Change getItem from returning InboxFragment to returning Fragment.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your post! I removed the Override and changed the return type but then I get errors inside the method after each of my cases stating.. "Type mismatch: cannot convert from InboxFragment to Fragment" and the quick fix suggests that I change Fragment return type of my method to InboxFragment which puts me back to where I started.

Comment: Does your inbox fragment derive from Fragment?  If not, you probably have big issues.  If so, that should be totally legal.

Comment: InboxFragment is setup to extend ListFragment

Comment: Are you using the support library anywhere?  I wonder if its mixing up the 3.x Fragment with the support fragment.  Looking at your imports it seems highly likely.  Use 1 type or the other everywhere, they can't be mixed.

Comment: I did have a v13 when everything else is v4! Nice catch. Now I am getting this error "The constructor FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined"

Comment: You need to be using the support library for Fragment and FragmentManager as well.  ALL of the fragment stuff needs to come from the support library.

Comment: Got it, had to change this line in my MainActivity: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, fragmentManager); //I was just calling the getFragmentManager method directly but I needed to run it as a constructor instead. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a type `InboxFragment` and int the line of code `return new FriendsFragment();` it wont accept it because it is not a type of `InboxFragment` but it is a type of `Fragment` so instead of returning `InboxFragment` from the `getItem` method change it to `Fragment`

**example:**

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your post! I did as you said but then I get errors inside the method after each of my cases stating.. "Type mismatch: cannot convert from InboxFragment to Fragment" and the quick fix suggests that I change Fragment return type of my method to InboxFragment which puts me back to where I started.

Comment: @ErinSKabbash is InboxFragment extends Fragment?

Comment: InboxFragment is setup to extend ListFragment

Comment: @ErinSKabbash and the FriendsFragment?

Comment: Same. I changed everything to v4 in my imports and it seemed to fix the issue.. but now I am getting the error: "The constructor FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined" on the super(fm); line

Comment: @ErinSKabbash change the import to: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

Comment: Got it, had to change this line in my MainActivity: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, fragmentManager); //I was just calling the getFragmentManager method directly but I needed to run it as a constructor instead. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

Is your class InboxFragment and FriendsFragment extends Fragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) ?
`android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Fragment` are not compatible to each other and FragmentPagerAdapter  supports `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` only.
Give it a try, it should work..

Comment: I changed everything to v4 in my imports and it seemed to fix the issue.. but now I am getting the error: "The constructor FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined" on the super(fm); line

Comment: and if it is android.app.ListFragment then use android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.
v4 was made in order to support applications which were built before ice-cream sandwich

Comment: use android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.
as in FragmentManager fragmentManager = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: Thank you, that was my final issue. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Does that mean .. i am getting a thumbs up :)